# payment gateway implementation in android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Can anyone tell me how to integrate mobile payment in my android app which can deal in INR.?

```
I did search for it but got no results.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried of exploring in paypal, Im not sure but i went through the forum of paypal long back and i got this link [In app purchase for android work for Indian account](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-mobile-xspace/does-app-purchase-android-work-indian-account).

And also take a look at these links provided from paypal for the developers.

1 ) [Countries Supported](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-approved-signup-countries-outside)
2 ) [Mobile Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/use-cases#mobile-payments)
3 ) [Android App](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/use-cases/android-app).

Just have a look at it. I think you wil get some ideas.

All the best.

Comment: thanks will definitely explore that but i think paypal doesnt support INR

Comment: I got these links explaining something related to your query, Take a look at it also. http://www.indian-share-tips.com/2011/09/paypal-auto-debit-facility-paypal.html, http://www.indian-share-tips.com/2011/12/funds-in-paypal-cannot-be-used-to-make.html.