# Google checkout alternatives in India

Tags: android, paypal, checkout

I want to implement in-app-billing in my Android app and I am from India. And I got to know that Google in-app-billing for Android is not supported for India i.e. I cannot have Google checkout account in India.

So can someone suggest me of some alternatives of Google in-app-billing for Android in India.

Answer (score 1):

`At present market is not allowing to Indian developers to proceed on this. From India we can buy apps not to sell. We can approach some other ways like` http://www.digi-go.com/android/index.html.

[Supported locations for merchants](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=15867&ctx=topic&answer=150324) : India is missing.

Comment: I don't want to sell app from India, the app will be free, the app will have products that will be chargeable. I am talking about this http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: @SunilSharma: I got your question, i think this link may give some idea : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514617/payment-gateway-implementation-in-android

Answer (score 0):

No this is not true, Google in-app billing is supported in India too. Since for the purpose of testing the in-app billing , I was able to purchase item. You can try it.

Comment: Well, I don't want to purchase products. I want to implement billing so that I would get money when people purchase some product from my app. For this, I need a Google checkout account, which would act as a payment gateway and transfer my earned money to checkout account. Well, now I know this checkout account can't be done through Google in India. So, if there are some alternatives please let me know.

Comment: @saba: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=15867&ctx=topic&answer=150324